# bash script for changing text file

Tags: bash, for-loop, text, replace, sed

i have a data file called params.dat, and i'd like to change the values in the file each time i run my code.

here's what i got so far

```
i=7.0
k=0
i=0
while [ $i -lt 10]
    do
    sed "3s/.*/$j 6.9 $j/" "28s/.*/image$i.bmp/" params.dat
    ((i++))
    ((k++))
    ((j=j-0.1))
done
```

the goal is to change the 3rd and 28th line of the date file from

```
7.0 7.0 7.0
```

to

```
6.9 7.0 6.9
```

basically minus the first and third value by 0.1 each time

and change the 28th line from

```
image0.bmp
```

to

```
image1.bmp
```

so first time my program takes 7.0 7.0 7.0 and image0.bmp

second time i wish it to run 6.9 7.0 6.9 and image1.bmp
and so on...

can anyone give me some tips how to accomplish it?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use awk:

```
#!/bin/bash

# set iter to be the number of times to execute the script
# alternatively use $1 and pass it as parameter to the script
iter=10
for (( i=1; i<=$iter; i++ )); do
    awk 'NR==3 {print $1-0.1, $2, $3-0.1; FS="[e.]"}
         NR==28 {print $1 "e" $2+1 "." $3}
         NR!=3 && NR!=28 {print}' params.dat > .tmpfile
    mv .tmpfile params.dat
done
```

The awk code will get to line 3 and subtract 0.1 from the first and third field, which are separated by a space by default. Then it will set the field separator to either an 'e' or a period. Then when we reach line 28 the line is split in three fields: `'imag' <field separator 'e'> '0' <field separator '.'> 'bmp'` Where we increase the second field and print the result. All other lines will just be printed the way they were.

Comment: My pleasure, thanks for accepting. If you need further explanation about awk or how to properly use it in the future, just ask. Try to read up on it, awk is extremely powerful and once you understand it, you'll notice you can use it for about anything while not hard to write.